# Golf me the Schlosberg Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

**Schlosberg Numbers**

In issue 5 of [Mathematical Reflections](https://www.awesomemath.org/mathematical-reflections/archives/), Dorin Andrica proposed the problem of characterising the positive integers n such that [image: \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor] is an even integer. Eight people submitted correct solutions showing that these are the integers n for which [image: \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor] is even. The published solution was by Joel Schlosberg, so I call them the Schlosberg numbers.

These numbers may be found in OEIS as sequence [A280682](http://oeis.org/A280682).

Your challenge is: given n, output the nth Schlosberg number. (0 or 1 indexed)

The first 50 Schlosberg numbers are:
0
4
5
6
7
8
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
100
101
102
103
104

Normal rules and the shortest code wins!

Comment: Why specifically the 1st 50? What about taking n and outputting a(n); outputting indefinitely; or taking n and outputting up to a(n)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan True, I went with the first 50, because that was what I was testing when I wrote it myself. while there are only a few answers I shall change it

Comment: ..and what about the other options which are oft-used for sequence based challenges?

Comment: @JonathanAllan sorry I'm not familiar with all the ins and outs of sequence challenges.

Comment: FYI for next time, it's generally not recommended to update the requirements after answers have been posted.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer yet asking for such specifics is bound to have people ask, so in this case, change, live & learn.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer okay thank you, I figures as there were only a few answers it would not have a major impact, but thank you

Comment: @JonathanAllan isn't that **exactly** what [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is for?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I am just saying generally, in this case it was probably the best option (the sandbox isn't *very* prominent for new users too).

Comment: @hakr14 supposedly

Comment: Can we use 0-based indexing, i.e., return **0** for input **0**?

Comment: @Dennis yes, will clarify

Comment: Given n how?  As a command-line argument?  As user input?  As a function argument?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the first documented solution was by Joel Schlosberg*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor if you go through the OEIS documentation, the link to the original solution to the question was first solved by Joel Schlosberg

Comment: @dan04 my understanding is than on PPCG that is up to you

Comment: What I see in that reference is that Schlosberg was one of eight people to solve a problem set by Dorin Andrica, so perhaps Andrica Numbers would be a more appropriate name. But the problem was to find all positive integers n such that `\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor` is an even integer. That problem doesn't appear anywhere in this question, so I can't understand how it makes any sense to refer to "*the solution*".

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor, I must not have read it clearly, feel free to modify the question to reflect this

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
(filter(even.floor.sqrt)[0..]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyMtM6cktUgjtSw1Ty8tJz@/SK@4sKhEM9pATy9WUVHzf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqNih1IzsQy9v@/5LScxPTi/7rJBQUA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
!fȯ¦2⌊√ΘN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzHtxPpDy4we9XQ96ph1bobf////TQ0A)

#### Explanation

```
!f(¦2⌊√)ΘN  -- 1-indexed number, eg: 4
        ΘN  -- natural numbers with 0: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9..
 f(    )    -- filter by
  (   √)    -- | square root: [0,1,1.414213562373095,1.7320508075688774,2,2.23606797749979,2.449489742783178,2.6457513110645903,2.82842712474619,3,..
  (  ⌊ )    -- | floor: [0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,..
  (¦2  )    -- | divisible by 2: [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,..
            -- : [0,4,5,6,7,8,..
!           -- get element: 6
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n and-~f(n-(k**.5%2<1),k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDoMgEAXQtT3FbAyMFSMaN6T2LjQWNejXEDfG4NVp3/7t5zFtaFNy/WLXz2AJpe@1AVkM6nYSSvqiqLq8eWku/VNzclsg0AwKFuNXdjWbR7aHGYd04oJpIqk3Xf/Lpo2C0w8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 k=(1+(8*n+1)**.5)//4
 return n+2*k*k+k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxNCoAgEAbQfaeY5ThCZT8QQYcJ0hLhMwZbdHqjA7x3v@XKGGs9fKDAMGtDaWNneRFYZ0Ta2XTd1JD68igIdpAkyaYashIognTH6Xnuf3trROE/MvUD)

A slightly different approach. First, if we subtract the sequence 0,1,2,... from the sequence of Schlosberg numbers, we get the sequence 0,3,3,3,3,3,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,21. Ignoring repetitions, the sequence 0,3,10,21,... is the sequence a(k) = 2k^2+k. If we can find k, the nth Schlosberg number is then n+a(k).

Given k, each a(k) is repeated 4k+1 times. Summing the length of the first k blocks, we get that the kth block of repetition ends at entry n=2k^2-k. Inverting this, we get k=(1+sqrt(8n+1))/4, which gives an explicit formula for k.

Comment: @Reesi82 `def f(n):k=(1+(8*n+1)**.5)//4;return n+2*k*k+k` saves three bytes of whitespace. In Python 2, you could replace `return` with `print`.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
{.[:I.0=2|3<.@%:@i.@*]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8L9aL9rKU8/A1qjG2EbPQdXKIVPPQSv2vyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagqnBfwA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I have updated the requirements to output the nth number. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @george - updated

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
function(n)(x=0:n^2)[!x^.5%/%1%%2][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jT1OjwtbAKi/OSDNasSJOz1RVX9VQVdUoNjov9n9xYkFBTqWGoZWpgU6a5n8A)

1-based indexing.

Answer (score 3):

### mIRC Scripting, 171 bytes

```
a {
  %s = 0
  %x = -1
  while 1 {
    inc %x 2
    %i = %x
    while %i {
      echo - %s
      inc %s
      dec %i
    }
    inc %x 2
    inc %s %x
  }
}
```

I didn't yet see this method for generating new Schlosberg numbers, so above is just a simple one that reads like pseudocode. We start at 0, display **1** number, increase **3**, display **5**, increase **7**, display **9**, etc. A simple pattern emerges.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
½ḞḂ¬Ʋ#Ṫ
```

A full program accepting `n` from STDIN

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//wr3huJ7huILCrMayI@G5qv//NTA)**

#### How?

```
½ḞḂ¬Ʋ#Ṫ - Main link: no arguments
     #  - take input (n) from STDIN & count up (i=0,1,...) collecting truthy results of:
    Ʋ   -   last four links as a monad:
½       -     square root
 Ḟ      -     floor      (½Ḟ could also be Æ½ - integer square root)
  Ḃ     -     bit (modulo by 2 - i.e. isOdd?)
   ¬    -     logical NOT
      Ṫ - tail (get the nth rather than the first n)
        - implicit print to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 10 bytes

```
e.fiI2s@Z2
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.fiI2s%40Z2&input=45&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
e.fiI2s@Z2 – Full program.
 .f        – Find the first N positive integers satisfying the requirements (var: Z).
e          – And take the last one (i.e. the Nth).
       @Z2 – Take the square root of Z.
      s    – Convert to an integer.
   iI2     – Check if 2 is invariant over applying GCD with the above (i.e. is it even?)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
µNtóÈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/ksObD3f8/29iCgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
È¬f v}iU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yKxmIHZ9aVU&input=OA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>36</s> 34 bytes

0-indexed

```js
n=>(g=i=>i**.5&1||n--?g(++i):i)(0)
```

2 bytes saved thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)

---

### Test it

```js
o.innerText=[...Array(50).keys()].map(
n=>(g=i=>i**.5&1||n--?g(++i):i)(0)
).join`, `
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 27 bytes

```perl6
{grep(+^*.sqrt%2,0..*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUBDO05Lr7iwqETVSMdAT09LM1olPrb2f3FipUKahkq8pkJafpFCnKmB9X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>45 44</s> 42 bytes

```ruby
->n,i=-1{(i+=1)**0.5%2<1||n+=1while n>i;i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ9NW17BaI1Pb1lBTS8tAz1TVyMawpiYPyC/PyMxJVcizy7TOrP2vYaCnZ2igqZeamJyhUF2TWaNQoJAWnRlb@x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); golfed `e>=++b*b` to `e/++b/b`.

```c
b,e;r(g){for(e=0;g&&++e;b&1&&--g)for(b=0;e/++b/b;);g=e;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtLCoQwDEDvIhga0qIyy@hhTI3Bgo6U2Q2evVbcvk8MFmMp4pWzM/yv3@x06tkAiJQFBoAQDB8ulWtHJJ0wsk3KV9nn7XDp/VL1aRz0w3jm7fitrmkX3/hqiBBrfQM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 84 bytes

```
proc S {x n\ 0 i\ 1} {while \$i<$x {if 1>int(floor([incr n]**.5))%2 {incr i}}
set n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxCoMwFAXQvV9xhwjqULTgUkp/wtFkCpE@SV8kPqkQ8u2xpevhiPWlrDFYjEgHWKMDafQZ6fMi76AVPdSBRDP6J7HUsw8h1hOxjWDTttehaarbN/yAcr5sTsC5CL0d0rrLhn9ezF1jGqEWkzF05QQ)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to Cows quack

Prompts for integer input:

```
(0,(~2|⌊r*.5)/r←⍳n×3)[n←⎕]
```

Explanation:

```
[n←⎕] prompts for input and selects the nth value of the result

(0,(~2|⌊r*.5)/r←⍳n×3)[n←⎕] create a vector of all results up to n×3
which works up to limit of machine. ×2 works up to n~10E7
```

Comment: Would `(0,(~2|⌊r*.5)/r←⍳n×3)[n←⎕]` work?

Comment: @Cowsquack. It would indeed for a 3 byte saving. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ḤḶ²Ḷœ^/ị@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiUPd2w7tAlIHJ0cp/9wd7fD////zQE)

Unfortunately it's longer than the other answer, but I do like this approach.

#### Explanation

The goal is to get the ranges from each even square to each subsequent odd square, excluding the odd square. We can do this by taking the symmetric set difference of some even number of ranges from zero to just below each square.

```
Ḥ   Double the input N to ensure it's even.
Ḷ   Lowered range, from 0 to 2N-1.
²   Square to get the first 2N squares.
Ḷ   Get the lowered ranges up to each square.
œ^/ Fold symmetric set difference over the ranges.
ị@  Select the Nth value.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 81 bytes

Sequence is 1-indexed [f(1) is 0]

```forth
: f 0 0 begin over s>f fsqrt f>s 1 and 0= - 1 under+ dup 3 pick = until drop 1- ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBDsIwDEPvfIXvqGgV2oVp@xdYklExNSXt@P2SyQdbtvVErb3DJqf1/oBgcL14Sxn6Y0NdBFK/1iBLRcQzE4YZweORie0KOgruKGn9YPaupR1kWhADJicyxuhnUiSn37Crb9OF@x8)

### Explanation

```forth
0 0              \ place the loop index and sequence index on the stack
begin            \ start an indefinite loop
   over          \ grab a copy of the loop index
   s>f sqrt f>s  \ get the square root of the index and truncate
   1 and 0=      \ determine if result is even
   -             \ if even, add 1 to sequence tracker (-1 is default for "true" in forth)
   1 under+      \ add 1 to the loop index
   dup 3 pick =  \ check if the current sequence position is the one that was requested
until            \ end the loop if condition above is true
drop 1-          \ drop the loop index and subtract 1 from the loop index to get the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0..n*4).select{|x|x**0.5%2<1}[n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNATy9Py0RTrzg1JzW5pLqmoqZCS8tAz1TVyMawNjovtvY/SImeqYGmXmpickZ1TWZNgUJadCZQAgA)

0-indexed. Instead of simple looping, this approach takes a large enough sequence of numbers and selects only those that fulfill the condition. The particular multiplier `n*4` is necessary to cover the case `n=1 => 4` (`n*n` doesn't fit here), and due to the pattern in the sequence, the value of the nth number fluctuates around `n*2`, so taking `n*4` should always be large enough.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are not the most efficient ways to solve the problem, however I do think they are interesting.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```hs
(!!)$do x<-[0,2..];[x^2..x^2+2*x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P91WQ1FRUyUlX6HCRjfaQMdITy/WOroiDkgDCW0jrYrY/7mJmXm2BUWZeSUquYkFCunRBnp6Rgax/wE)

## Haskell, <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```hs
y#x=not$y^2>x||(y+1)#x
(filter(0#)[0..]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1K5wjYvv0SlMs7IrqKmRqNS21BTuYIr3VYjLTOnJLVIw0BZM9pATy9WUVHzf25iZp5tQVFmXolKbmKBQjpIwsgg9j8A)

Comment: You're better off using [`do`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P91WQ1FRUyUlX6HCRjfaQMdITy/WOroiDkhrVGgbasYZ6RrG/s9NzMyzLSjKzCtRyU0sUEiPNtDTMzKI/Q8A) in cases like this

Comment: Also `(x+1)^2-1 = x^2+2*x`

Comment: @H.PWiz Thanks! I tried a `do`, but I didn't know you could use a semicolon like that.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 31 bytes

```
sn_1[d]sD[1+dv2%0=Dzln!<M]dsMxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2rwvzgv3jA6JbbYJdpQO6XMSNXA1qUqJ0/Rxjc2pdi3ouB/dEpxXp6pRYCxUUByvGEOUCi2OERBQUG5JLW4RKG4NLMkVaG8KLGgILWIyzAnpELBCEQYgwhDAzDfFESamQHJ/wA) *(1-indexed)*

Rather simple. `D` is a macro that just duplicates the top-of-stack. We begin by storing the user's input in `n`, and placing negative 1 (`_1`) on the stack. Macro `M` increments the top-of-stack by one, duplicates it, and then does the necessary sqrt mod 2 (`v2%`). `dc`'s precision is zero by default, so doing a square root is, by default, actually the floor of the square root. `0=D` compares our `v2%` to zero, and runs our duplication macro (`D`) if true. `z` fetches the stack depth, and then `ln!<M` compares this to `n` (our target), continuing to run `M` until we get to the value we were looking for. Finally, `p`rint it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```scala
Stream.from(0).filter(n=>math.sqrt(n).toInt%2==0)(_)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY0xCsJAEEV7TzEIwi7iEtRChQgWFhZWYiUiY8xqJDsbN6MikpPY2GjjibyNI1p9Prz__u1ZJphj57Wot8ifMVB9-R779T5NGKaYEVxrAJvUgpOiMGzLAYxCwMtixiGj7VIPYE4ZQyykoAAnzMFKfRzZtnrvrnApOmODdyrSxmY5p0FRPHTIO1MeAivShv2EuNGO40irlf5vm1-fioA9dPvaOCyUFYMXYbJThfxzTlpeq1r1m9zvv_wA)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=0,j=1)=>n<j?n+i:f(n-j,i-2*~j,j+4)
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 value=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>0
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @JonathanFrech.

Comment: `i+j+j+2` <=> `i-~j*2`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 39 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.875 bytes

```
≬√⌊₂l
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJHPSIsIiIsIuKJrOKImuKMiuKCgmwiLCIiLCI1OSJd)

Bitstring:

```
111111000101100000001111100000100100000
```

lol vyncode